# Cant use req.user in another controller

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm using an angular-fullstack-generator with sequelize.

I have a problem, i need to use the logged User object (req.user) in another controller (with another Model), not in User controller.

But req.user in the other controller is undefined. any idea?

Thanks

---

I have users and buttons (i'm using sequelize instead of mongoose) and i have an association between users and buttons, so when I create a button, I have to add the user object (logged) in a button (to the association table). Do u know how I cant take the User Object for use it in the .complete() after .save() when i save a new button?

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
var newButton = Button.build(req.body);
newButton.provider = 'local';

newButton
.save()
.complete(function(err, newButton, user) {
if (err) return handleError(res, err);
newButton.addUser(req.user);
...
```

req.user is undefined or null here :S

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this to add the user to req.

```
 req.logIn(user, function(err) 
    {
    }
    );
```

refer this sample :
https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo

Comment: In passport doc: "Note: passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically" and i used it in the index.js of auth.

i cant take the logged user object in another controller in the server :S. Thanks